# Resize MessageBox and Exception Fonts

Tags: c#

I am editing a program for a smaller device in csharp and the messages that pop up are too small. So, I want to make them bigger. The current code uses "messageHandler" to make the window pop up with the text. Here is what I am looking at:

```
this.messageHandler("Parameters Loaded", "Parameters Loaded Successfully");
```

So, I want to make the font larger since making the font larger should make the text and potentially the window bigger as well. I read that perhaps I should attempt to make a new class, but I am a bit confused on how to proceed. Thank you.

edit:

I think this is the original definition:

```
private void messageHandler(string title, Exception ex)
{
    this.messageHandler(title, ex.Message);
}
```

I believe I am using WinForms.

Comment: What framework are you using? Is this WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or something completely different. What does the definition of `messageHandler` look like? And what have you tried?

Comment: Show us please the code that does the actual displaying of the message. "this.messageHandler" doesn't tell us anything...

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I am editing someone elses code, but I believe it is Winforms since there is an include for it at the top. As for the message handler I am not too sure. I just see messageHandler() with text in it all over the place. Occasionally, I will see a messageBox call or something, but I just see a lot of messageHandler calls. What I want to do is make a new form I guess, I do see some code that attempted this and took parameters. I also fund this: private void messageHandler(string title, Exception ex)
        {
            this.messageHandler(title, ex.Message);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically I made a new class that extended a form. I then passed any text or variables to buttons and text boxes I made in that form. I then replaced certain "messageHandler" calls with my own function that utilized that class. Here is an example of the function I used from the class:

```
//Message or exception box with an okay button
public void okNewMessageBox(string title, string message)
{
    NewMessageBox msgResized = new NewMessageBox(title, message);
    msgResized.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    msgResized.Show();
}
```

Here is the class file with one text box set to read only and an okay button that closes the window:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class NewMessageBox : Form
{
    private TextBox textBoxMessage;
    private Button buttonOK;


    public NewMessageBox(string title, string message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = title;
        this.textBoxMessage.Text = message;
        this.Deactivate += MyDeactivateHandler;
        this.textBoxMessage.ReadOnly = true;
    }


    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
            this.buttonOK = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.textBoxMessage = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // buttonOK
            // 
            this.buttonOK.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(171, 161);
            this.buttonOK.Name = "buttonOK";
            this.buttonOK.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 44);
            this.buttonOK.TabIndex = 0;
            this.buttonOK.Text = "OK";
            this.buttonOK.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.buttonOK.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonOK_Click);
            // 
            // textBoxMessage
            // 
            this.textBoxMessage.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBoxMessage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 36);
            this.textBoxMessage.Name = "textBoxMessage";
            this.textBoxMessage.ReadOnly = true;
            this.textBoxMessage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(411, 38);
            this.textBoxMessage.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // NewMessageBox
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(468, 236);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBoxMessage);
            this.Controls.Add(this.buttonOK);
            this.Name = "NewMessageBox";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.NewMessageBox_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

    }


    public string message { get; set; }

    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    protected void MyDeactivateHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void NewMessageBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```